# How can I wait for the observable in Angularfire 2?

Tags: angular, firebase, observable, angularfire2

The problem is that the chat.name display a blank at first because the mapping hasn't been finished yet. Is there any way to wait for the mapping before it updates the data?

```
this.chats = this.af.database.list('/chats/' + this.mainService.getUserId(), {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'timestamp'
  }
}).map((chats) => {
    return chats.map( chat => {
        chat.name = this.af.database.object(`/users/${chat.uid}`);
        return chat;
    })
});
```

Here's the UI.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let chat of chats | async">
       {{ (chat.name | async)?.name }} : {{  chat.lastMessage }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

see this answer - [Nested Observables in Angular2 using AngularFire2 not rendering in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37060067/nested-observables-in-angular2-using-angularfire2-not-rendering-in-view/37064456#37064456)

But I suspect you will need to add the elvis operator to the HTML page

`{{ chat?.name }}`

Comment: Actually, I saw that one already a while ago. I can display the value though. It is just that once I push a message, it will stay blank for a few seconds then display the chat.name.

Comment: i dont have an UI code to review so it is kinda hard to provide any guidance here?

Comment: I just edited my post. Sorry about that. The issue is, at first it will display the last message then after a few seconds it will show the chat.name. Thank you.

If I try to wrap it around a div and do a *ngIf, it will annoying for the user when there's a new updates.

Thank you