# Firebase: fetch data for list

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

I have a tagging system implemented in Firebase, using following structure:

[image]

Now, I want to create a list of all photos with tag of id tag_id_1. First, I need to retrieve /tags/tag_id_1 for collecting the ids, then I need to retrieve the corresponding photo data from Firebase.

I'm using the Angularfire2 library, along with Ionic 2.

The code I've written up until now is something like this:

```
this.posts = af.database.list('/tags/tag_id_1')
      .map((items) => {
          console.log(items);
          return items.filter(item => item.$value).map((item) => {
              let id = item.$key;
              return af.database.object(`/photos/${id}`);
          });
      });
this.posts.subscribe();

<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let post of posts | async" class="text" >
    {{ post }}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

But it doesn't seem to do the trick. Moreover, this would generate a new array of photo objects every time an id is added to the collection. Therefor, I tried implementing it differently:

```
this.posts = Observable.create(observer => {
  var ref = _cloud.ref('/tags/tag_id_1');

  ref.on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.key);
    observer.next(_cloud.object(`/photos/${snapshot.key}`));
  });
});
this.posts.subscribe();
```

Which would only fire the updated photo. But I can't get it to render.

Has anyone ever had a similar issue? I had a look at [Nested Observables in Angular2 using AngularFire2 not rendering in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37060067/nested-observables-in-angular2-using-angularfire2-not-rendering-in-view) (my first solution is inspired on that post), but I can't get it to work properly.

Comment: /tags/tag_id_1: { photo_id_1: true, photo_id_4: true, photo_id_5: true } this is an object ? y r u using af.database.list here ?

Comment: No. I've updated the question with a picture to show what I mean.