# Using ngFor item as key in an Observable list

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire, angularfire2, angularfire5

I'm extremely new to Angular and really excited so far at how powerful it is.
I'm using the angularfire2 library to retrieve two separate lists from firebase (*.ts):

```
this.list1= this.db.list("list1").valueChanges();
this.list2= this.db.list("list2").valueChanges();
```

While looping over the first list with *ngFor, I want to use list1.val as a key in obtaining a list2 value

```
(list2[list1.val].name).
```

I run into lots of different errors when trying different things, but the most prominent is this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'party' of undefined
```

This is what my *.html file looks like currently (was attempting some magic with async):

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let item1 of list1| async">
  <ion-col>{{item1.val}}</ion-col>
  <!--different attempts-->
  <ion-col>{{(list2|async)[item1.val].name}}</ion-col>
  <ion-col>{{(list2[item1.val].name| async)}}</ion-col>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

I'm thinking that ngFor is somehow changing the structure of list1 from:

```
Observable<any[]>
```

to an object that's more consumable. Without that, my list2 object is actually something that cannot be indexed unless some sort of transformation happens? Help :)

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to figure this out with some help from this post: [Nested Observables in Angular2 using AngularFire2 not rendering in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37060067/nested-observables-in-angular2-using-angularfire2-not-rendering-in-view)

The trick was to make a map function which mapped an object observable to my second node:

```
this.list1= this.db.list("list1").snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
  return changes.map(list1Obj => ({
    l1Key: list1Obj.payload.key,
    list2Obj: this.db.object('list2/' + list1Obj.payload.key).valueChanges()
  }));
});
```

Then, I was able to display it in the html like so:

```
  <ion-row *ngFor="let item1 of list1| async">
    <ion-col>{{item1.l1Key}}</ion-col>
    <ion-col>{{((item1.list2Obj | async)?.name)}}</ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```